# Unable to find SQL Server Configuration Manager

Tags: sql-server

I installed SQL Server Management Studio and it asked me to connect to a server. After searching online I found SQL Server Config Manager is required to do that but after both component management and searching for the `.msc` I'm unable to find it.

[SQL Server Management Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOMbI.png)

[Services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZ3Kt.png)

Comment: SQL Server Configuration Manager is installed with the **database engine** - but Mgmt Studio is only the GUI management tool - **NOT** the engine! So if you really want to have a database on your system, you must install SQL Server - the **database engine** - not just SSMS ....

Comment: @marc_s ah i understand. Thanks for clearing it out, don't know how this wasn't one of the answers online.